# Regex url rewriting not working for arguments with spaces

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite this 
url:
npc.php?id=3141&name=a+cool+guy 
to 
    /npcview-3141-a-cool-guy.html

using the following rules

```
RewriteRule npcview-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ npc?npcid=$1&name=$2
```

It works fine for arguments that dont have spaces eg

```
npcview-341-man.html
```

The server output is as expected:

```
Array ( [npcid] => 341[name] => Man)
```

But if I do something with spaces eg

```
npcview-881-a-cool-guy.html
```

I get

```
 Array ( [npcid] => 8834-a-cool [name] => guy.html )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is use of `.*` in your regex. Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule npcview-([^-]+)-(.+?)\.html$ npc?npcid=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```